# Herança JPA Inheritance.JOINED não funciona como deveria

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Olá, tenho as seguintes classes *Pessoa*, *PessoaFisica* e *PessoaJuridica*. As duas últimas classes compartilham a mesma chave primária da classe *Pessoa*, isto é, a chave primária e chave estrangeira das tabelas *PessoaFisica* e *PessoaJuridica* correspondem a chave primária da tabela *Pessoa*. Se liguem aí no diagrama:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Pessoa.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="pessoa")
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long idpessoa;

    @NotNull(message = "O atributo nome não pode ser nulo.")
    @Column(nullable=false, length=255)
    private String nome;
}
```

**PessoaFisica.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa_fisica")
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
    private String cpf;

}
```

**PessoaJuridica.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa_juridica")
public class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 18)
    private String cnpj;


}
```

Tudo deve funcionar assim, eu persisto uma pessoa no banco. Com o id dessa pessoa eu preciso associar ela para ou uma pessoa física ou uma pessoa jurídica, isto é, eu não posso ter uma pessoa física e jurídica com o mesmo id.
Na hora de salvar e recuperar uma pessoa tudo ok, mas se por exemplo, for salvar uma pessoa física acontece um erro dizendo que nome não pode ser nulo. Isto é confuso já que pelo conceito de `InheritanceType.JOINED` cada classe deveria apenas persistir os seus próprios atributos, a única coisa compartilhada é a chave primária. Estou errado? A única coisa que desejo é salvar o `cpf`, `idpessoa`, apenas os atributos que pertencem a subclasse e sua respectiva entidade.

Comment: Poderia compartilhar o erro que vc está recebendo no console?

Comment: `"javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes` ... `during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='O atributo nome não pode ser nulo.', propertyPath=nome, rootBeanClass=class` @ErickLuz

Comment: a 3 anos eu respondi a uma dúvida parecida, veja se funciona. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43139/heran%C3%A7a-com-jpa

Comment: @AndréMartins o TABLE_PER_CLASS não funciona para o propósito dessa implementação, eu preciso que sejam geradas chaves IDENTITY, o que o TABLE_PER_CLASS não permite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda a solução foi relatada nos comentários:

**Pessoa.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="pessoa")
public abstract class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long idpessoa;

    @NotNull(message = "O atributo nome não pode ser nulo.")
    @Column(nullable=false, length=255)
    private String nome;
}
```

**PessoaFisica.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa_fisica")
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
    private String cpf;

}
```

**PessoaJuridica.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa_juridica")
public class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 18)
    private String cnpj;

}
```

A classe *Pessoa.java* fica disponível para requisições `GET` e `DELETE`. Mas por ser abstract é impossível instanciar um objeto através de um `POST`. Para instanciar uma pessoa física eu preciso colocar os atributos de pessoa, como nome e os restantes dos atributos da própria classe pessoa física. Assim vale o mesmo para pessoa jurídica. Deste modo não existe uma pessoa física ou jurídica que possua o mesmo id.

Comment: Ainda estou obtendo o mesmo erro. Agora estou pensando que o problema deva existir com a utilização do Lombok...

Comment: Como você esta testando a inserção dos dados? Junit? método main? jsf? etc..

Comment: Requisição `POST`, um JSON body. `{ "cpf": "11111111111", "idpessoa": 1  }`

Comment: Experimenta colocar o campo 'nome' nesse json, se o erro persistir implementa o método toString() na classe filha, e coloca aqui o print do que esta aparecendo no console no System.out.println(obj.toString());

Comment: Olá, cara eu consegui resolver o problema. Tornei a classe Pessoa asbtrata, e a única coisa que faço é um POST JSON request body  para uma pessoa física ou uma pessoa jurídica sem precisar passar o "idpessoa", pois na hora do POST o id é gerado em pessoa e herdado para o tipo de pessoa que está sendo persistido na hora, logo não podemos ter um mesmo id pra pessoa física em pessoa jurídica ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: E agora faz muita lógica ter a classe Pessoa como abstrata já que ela não precisa ser um recurso na minha API (/pessoas por exemplo), apenas uma classe que me ajuda a gerenciar ids e atributos comuns para tipos de pessoas do lado do banco de dados. Se eu fizer um `SELECT * FROM pessoa` eu listo todas as pessoas físicas e jurídicas.

Comment: Quer ter a honra de editar a resposta? É só colocar `abstract` em Pessoa e apagar os construtores. Faz isso e referência aos meus comentários aqui, vou dar check. Valeu e muito obrigado pela ajuda aí \o/

Comment: Ahh entendi, mas ate mesmo pra eu entender, você fez funcionar sem os construtores? digo se você tirar/tirou, continua funcionando?

Comment: Eu não usei os construtores não, deixei o Lombok cuidar disso mesmo... e por curiosidade e felicidade estou conseguindo utilizar a classe pessoa como recurso da minha API.